# Have adb.exe at specified location but still have "adb.exe is obsolete and has serious performance problems" dialog box

Tags: android-studio, adb

I have the adb.exe at "`../AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe`" and even checked the virus chest of antivirus everything is fine.
But still get the dialogue box saying

> "adb.exe is obsolete and has serious performance problems".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked out for me was after

> - Create Virtual Device
> - Choose a device
> - select `Q API Level 29 image` with target as `Android 10.0 (Google APIs)`
>   not just `Android 10.0`

and proceed as usual.
[image]

Hope its useful for you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late but the accepted solution didn't work for me. However the following did:

- SDK Manager -> SDK Tools
- Delete current *Android SDK Build-Tools* even if it is the latest version. In my case, I observed it also  uninstalled a lot of previous versions
- Restart Adroid Studio
- Install the latest *Android SDK Build-Tools*
- Restart Adroid Studio

I suspect the problem happened due to some sort of error in incremental updates of adb